# access idx-analytics-data-api through a browser

Tags: api, edx

I am trying to access the Open edX data Analytics API v0 alpha as I would like to download the problem grades data.

In the [documentation](https://edx-data-analytics-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html) on setting up the API it mentioned *Test the Data Analytics API* by "In a browser, go to: `http://<server-name>:<port>/docs/#!/api/`
Enter a valid key and click Explore."

**May I know what is the server-name and port number here refers to?
Also what is the Docs/#! refers to here.**

I tried to look for API url online, but could not find it either. 
Also I am assuming I need to get authorization through Oauth2 as well.

As this is the first time I am trying to access API to download data, i would really appreciate your help with the questions above

Answer (score 0):

in this

```
http://<server-name>:<port>/docs/#!/api/
<server-name>
```

refers to the ip address of the server where you are running the edx-analytics

```
<port>
```

refers to port

sample url could be http://192.168.10.110:8085/docs/#!/api/